# What is a "UEFI bootloader"?

Tags: uefi, firmware

I was under the assumption that UEFI is a spec/implementation.

Therefore you package it with another bootloader (e.g. Grub2).

There's no such thing as a singular UEFI bootloader.

In essence **U-boot** is a bootloader all by itself, but there is no such idea of a "one and done" UEFI bootloader. There are various options of UEFI capable bootloaders.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: I don't know how to add more context. When talking to others they simply state "the UEFI boot loader." I do not know what that means and cannot Google it.

Comment: So link to instances of “talking to others”. It’s an ambiguous term after all. For example, I could say that Grub2 is an UEFI bootloader.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT it was helpful. It reiterates most of the stuff I have read on what UEFI is. Essentially from what I gather there is no such thing as "a UEFI bootloader." There are many bootloaders capable of being UEFI compliant. I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer with Breakdown**

UEFI is firmware for computers [developed and published by Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/unified-extensible-firmware-interface/efi-specifications-general-technology.html). Unlike most BIOS firmware, UEFI firmware can be found on systems which are not in the [IBM PC compatible class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_compatible).

**Extensible Firmware**

UEFI is an extension of firmware like BIOS but <sup>(1)</sup>it can read from entries from disk partitions by not just booting from a disk but <sup>(2)</sup>booting from a specific boot loader in a specific location on a specific disk.

**Bootloader Compatibility for Execution by UEFI**

The [UEFI spec](http://www.uefi.org/specifications) defines the executable format requiring all UEFI firmwares to be capable of executing code in that format. When a bootloader is written for native UEFI, it is written in this format.

**Backwards Compatible**

For backward compatibility, most UEFI firmware can boot a system just like BIOS firmware and look for a MBR and run the boot loader from there as well. Depending on the firmware this may be called **BIOS legacy mode**, **BIOS compatibility mode**, or other similar terms.

---

### Comparison Reference

> ### UEFI and U-Boot behave very differently
>
> - **U-Boot**
>
>   - Boot variables specify kernel, initrd and command line
>   - Currently no default behaviour for booting automatically
> - **UEFI**
>
>   - Specification for how to choose boot device.
>   - Specification for ABI and execution environment.
>
> <sub>[source](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Korea%20Linux%20Forum%202013%20-%20UEFI%20and%20ARM.pdf)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Consider UEFI more like a BIOS, or a layer to get things started for a computer. If you were to look at the workflow of how a computer starts, you might say it starts with the CMOS, then to the BIOS then an OS **with** a boot loader. So you could say Grub2 is a UEFI bootloader, but you can also simply state:

A UEFI Bootloader is any bootloader capable of reading from a UEFI type firmware.

Comment: Thanks for an answer I was actually looking for. Essentially there is no such thing as "a UEFI bootloader", more of a UEFI capable bootloader.

Comment: @user_ABCD: Something like that, or more of "bootloader written for UEFI" – in the same way that programs can be written for Windows or MS-DOS. Grub2, rEFInd, systemd-boot are common.